# IServiceProvider.GetSingleton resolving null in Asp.Net Core DI

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

During the `ConfigureServices()` bootstrapping of my application I register mostly transients and scoped types with the Dependency Injection framework that ships with .Net Core. However, I do have one type that is registered as a singleton is my `InProcessBus` (I am using a CQRS styled architecture).

```
services.AddSingleton<InProcessBus>(new InProcessBus());
...         
services.AddSingleton<ICommandSender>(y => y.GetService<InProcessBus>());
services.AddSingleton<IEventPublisher>(y => y.GetService<InProcessBus>());
```

As you can see I am using implementation factory functions for the actual types that will be used in the controller of the APIs. The really bizarre thing is when the controller loads and the runtime tries to constructor inject `ICommandSender` it fails to resolve it and reports an error.

If I inspect the `serviceCollection` I can see that the implementationFactory is correctly registered against the type under the `ImplementationInstance` property.

Delving deeper and direct resolving the type at the end of the `Startup` class' `ConfigureServices()` method affirms that the container is resolving `null`.

```
ServiceLocator.GetService<ICommandSender>() // Is Null
```

Why would a ImplementationFactory method against a singleton that clearly exists in the container not resolve at runtime?

Comment: That's odd. Though you may want to avoid using `y.GetService<T>()` and use `y.GetRequiredService<T>()` which will throw an exception if it can't be resolved, rather than returning null. Though that likely won't resolve your issue. Is there more to it? Also you can't resolve it inside `ConfigureServices`, at that time the container is not built yet. Earlierst point you can resolve services is in `Configure` method (if you use the standard Startup.cs which comes with the templates)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the built-in container? CQRS architecture styles are really powerful since they make it really easy to apply cross-cutting concerns using decorators. It's impossible to apply generic decorators using the built-in container.

Comment: @Tseng, thanks for the GetRequiredService tip, an explicit exception is better than null. Usually would not be able to resolve yes, but I used BuildServiceProvider() to build my own provider to test with inline when I was having the issue...

Comment: @Steven, I wrap the container use a custom cross framework container contract, that way I don't have a hard container dependency any any particular container. This particular CQRS implementation is a very lite one since I am actually mostly playing around with .Net Core and Standard.

Comment: @SarelEsterhuizen: you wouldn't have any dependency with the built in either. The only place where you need a reference is in your composition root. In all your other layers you just inject interfaces of the services you need in your classes constructor or `IEnumerable<T>` if you need all registrations for a certain type. ServiceLocator is just a really bad pattern.Also see my comments below, you will have other issue because you'll likely now have two container instances,one of which never gets disposed. So your scoped services may become singletons in your service locator if used incorrectly

Comment: Which also applies to your transients if you don't dispose them yourself, they may hold resources for longer than expected (until gc when there are no references). In normal ASP.NET Core pipeline transients gets disposed at the end of request, with your service locator they won't. Neither do the scoped ones unless you expicitely create child scopes and dispose the scope as a whole

Comment: @Tseng, you are assuming that all the components are using the same host (ASP Core). In my case I might ultimately take the command stack of the architecture and build a separate executable that I deploy to Azure Service Fabric or something. I want to maintain the flexibility of deciding which DI container to use (or not) depending on the host type. Hence why for my domain and infrastructure portable CLIs I only rely on my own injection contract since I want those layers to be agnostic regarding the underlying tech.

Comment: But you will still only have to only reference only in the composition root (Main in cosole application, startup in ASP.NET Core, global.asax in ASP.NET 4, WPF Main method too, UWP in the inside your App classes 'OnInitializeAsync' etc.). Your layers, Domain Layer or Project libraries containing Command handlers will NEVER know about the IoC container you use. Only requirement is to never use `IServiceProvider` in this layers and when you do it, it should tell you that its in the wrong layer and belongs to the application layer instead

Comment: Maybe your main confusion comes from the fact, that its the default mechanism in ASP.NET Core. But `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package has no dependency on ASP.NET Core! You can run it in Console application and even in WPF, UWP or ASP.NET 4 applications. All it needs is .NET Framework 4.5.1 or .NET Core (targets `netstandard1.1`)

Comment: @Tseng, not confused at all. I think we are talking past one another. I understand that the MS package is separate and that it would not touch the rest of my layers. I was referring to the fact that I have an inverted service locator in the other layers so that those layers do not know about the underlying DI framework. I know that the ServiceLocator pattern is considered by many to be an anti pattern and as such I mostly use constructor DI injection, but I want to have the option to do service location if I need to. As such I wrap the  MS DI container and expose it only using interfaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131906/discussion-between-sarel-esterhuizen-and-tseng).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found what was wrong and thought I would post it here since there is an important lesson in it.

**The Short answer:**

Defer `serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()` to after you have registered all your singleton instances otherwise it will not be able to resolve them.

**The Long answer:**

The problem actually had nothing to do with the asp core DI container (well sorta). The problem is with the timing of when I call `BuildServiceProvider` on the `serviceCollection` instance to provide me with a `IServiceProvider`.

In my implementation I have implemented a `ServiceLocator` pattern that wraps the DI framework that ships with core so that I don't introduce an extra dependency in my other architectural layers. When I construct my `IServiceContainer` based locator I immediately resolve the `ServiceProvider`

```
public ServiceLocator(
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
        _serviceProvider = _serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

And this is where the problem crept in. The time when that `ServiceProvider` get created obviously does not matter for `Transients` and `Scoped` instances. ***But for Singletons that have a managed lifespan it does***. You need to defer the creation of your `ServiceProviders` after all the registrations.

From my question the `ServiceLocator` was constructed before the snippets meaning that the Singleton instance would not have been accessible to the `ServiceProvider` when the implementationFactory function executes.

By deferring the creation of the ServiceProvider to the first time my application resolves one of my custom types during runtime solved the problem.

Comment: You will likely have other issues with this approach (ignoring the fact that Service Locator is anti-pattern and beats the whole purpose of DI/IoC): You will now have two containers in your system, one that ASP.NET Core creates before calling `Configure` and one you created for your anti-pattern locator, which will be an issue with scoped services (DbContext) as your services that use ASP.NET Core IoC and the ones using your service locator will have different instances, calling `SaveChanges()` for example won't safe the changes from your other context and you lose the Unit of Work advantage

Comment: Also could you elaborate "_pattern that wraps the DI framework that ships with core so that I don't introduce an extra dependency in my other architectural layers_"? You don't need any other dependencies in your other layers to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. You only need it in the web application (where you construct your object graph in the composition root). Your approach seems very wrong from architectual point of view and it creates a hard dependency and becomes hard/impossible to unit test